# Fragment visible on the background

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an application that has three fragments which are defined in an XML file:

```
 [HeaderFragment] 

 [MainFragment] 

 [FooterFragment]
```

The first screen initiates the three fragments, the Header- and FooterFragment are static so will not change content.

The MainFragment is initial a menu with buttons and a transparant background (`MenuFragment`). When I click an item in the menu I replace the `MenuFragment` with a new fragment (`DetailsFragment`) like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();
transaction.replace(R.id.content_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(newFragment.getTag());
transaction.commit();
```

The `DetailFragment` shows up and when I press back, the `MenuFragment` appears and everything works how it should.

**Here is my problem:**

Inside my `DetailFragment`, I have a toggle option to filter the content, this is a button. When this is clicked, the `DetailFragmentFiltered` replaces the `DetailFragment` on the same way as the code above states. The only difference is that I don't add it to the BackStack because after filtering and pressing Back.. I still want to return to the `MenuFragment`.

When I clicked the filter button and press Back, the `DetailFragment` (or `DetailFragmentFiltered`) is shown behind my `MenuFragment`. Afcourse, I don't want this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't use a static fragment relation to an XML by setting the first fragment as "android:name" in the layout.

Make with framelayouts the layout of the XML and add the fragments flexibly as shown in this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html