# Replaced fragment still visible

Tags: android, fragment

When I start my app it runs an `AsyncTask` to load up and then in `onPostExecute`, I then `setContentView` to the new layout then add a fragment with two buttons offering two modes by an add `FragmentTransaction`. After one of the two modes is clicked, it then replaces the fragment with yet another `FragmentTransaction` using the replace method.

If the app crashes it returns to the first screen, loading up the two buttons offering the two modes. In this case if either mode is selected, the second fragment is loaded but is now the background is suddenly transparent showing the two buttons below and they remain clickable. If they are clicked again they properly replace the fragment so that it isn't visible below. This is just weird, I can't understand what could cause this.

I've researched and seen these two similar questions, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518804/fragment-visible-on-the-background) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958555/android-replace-fragment-still-displays-some-of-the-replaced-fragment), which suggested that it might be because the ID is wrong or I have defined the fragment in XML. Neither of these two factors are the case.

My code is shown below:

Below I replace the loading screen.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new ModeFragment())
                .commit();
            }
```

After which, when a button is clicked I pass the fragment I wish to replace the current with into this method below:

```
private void replaceCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

This works the first time, however if a crash occurs then the app returns to the first fragment and the second time this method is passed, the new replacing fragment is semi-invisible. Clicking the button on the first fragment again calls this method again and it is now fine.

Obviously I don't want the app to crash so this shouldn't occur, but I get this feeling that there's something wrong with how I'm writing my code.

Answer (score 11):

I've had the same problem happen to me, and it was because I loaded a fragment in the OnCreate of my Activity, without checking if there was a savedInstanceState, so android first reopen all old fragments, then do the OnCreate, which added the fragment over the old ones **without replacing them** so when you navigate to another fragment, it only replaces the top one, but not the bottom one, so you will see the fragments under it.

Might not be exactly the same thing for you, but it might help you figure it out.

Comment: This should be a comment than an answer.

Comment: My problem was with the background attribute in the HoloGraph element (a little library for drawing charts) in my summary's XML layout file. I deleted that attribute and it worked. I was replacing my fragment after detaching, in order to refresh the fragment, but indeed I didn't need to replace the fragment, I only needed to detach, attach (calls fragment's onCreateView), and commit. If you have a similar issue and you have to pass data to your fragment, I suggest change where you store the data from the fragment's bundle to some fields in another class. Access them in fragment's onCreateView.